# Logger.getLog() is not working: Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to view my log from the sheet front end, I tried following workaround but it seems `getLog()` function is not working.

```
// log adding function
function addLogs()
{
  Logger.log("Adding my test log");
}

// log display function
function viewLog()
{
  var logs = Logger.getLog(); // issue is here
  Browser.msgBox(logs); // gives empty
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService 
     .createHtmlOutput(logs)
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(500);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Sheet Log'); // gives empty
}
```

Comment: what error did you get from this? You can also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#getlog) about getLog().

Comment: @KENdi There is no error, it return empty string. looks like when I call viewLog() function later, log has cleared

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your functions together as a nested function. When you run the code, you have added to the log in one function, and called an empty log in the other.

You will either need to add to the log and call it in the same function or nest the functions together so that when you run the topmost function, it runs all processes.

Comment: Yes, that's work when they both combined together. What i wanted to view the log later.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as the answer so that the question can be found by others later.

Answer (score -1):

Did you call the function addLogs() at all? It's not going to run on it's own and hence the log will be empty at the beginning. Correct behaviour.